# DBT Cloud: Trying to conditional create tables in a DB based on variable

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

In my profiles.yml file I have vars declared:

```
vars:
  database: dbtworkshop
```

And then within my models I have the following:

```
{{ config(database= var('database') ) }}

select
    *
from {{var('database')}}.staging.orders
```

The query appears to be compiling correctly however I'm getting an error when passing the vars at runtime

```
dbt run --vars '{"database":"a"}'
```

I get the error:

```
Postgres adapter: Postgres error: cross-database reference to database "a" is not supported
```

I'm not sure whether doing something like this (ie having models that I want to create in a database which changes based on the variable passed at runtime) is even possible using dbt or if I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you building every model in one database? Or are some models in different databases?

Comment: Some models are different databases, but I want to keep them all in the same project

Comment: I find myself a bit puzzled - fundamentally this looks like a postgres error that's been propagated through to DBT. I know RedShift descends from postgres, but does it throw postgres errors? I don't think it's related to the use of variables; I _suspect_ you'll find that a model that just does `SELECT * FROM dbtworkshop.staging.orders` (no templating) fails, but let us know if that's not the case.

Comment: Yes also fails, it seems to be the cross database error, but according to redshift docs it appears cross database queries are in fact allowed so I'm not positive why this is occuring.

Comment: And can you get cross DB queries working under _any_  circumstances (i.e. outside of DBT)? If not, I think you would be likely to get better answers if you were to rewrite the question to remove references to DBT variables, change the title and the tags etc. I did have a go at claiming your bounty, but in the end Redshift is not something I've worked with personally.

Answer (score 0):

When using Redshift with dbt, make sure to set `ra3_node = true` in your `profiles.yml` since the older node type of DC2 does not actually support cross database queries. RA3 and Serverless support it, and for those the setting is required.

See https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-setups/redshift-setup

Comment: Even with that in my profile.yml I'm getting the same error

Comment: What dbt version are you running?